# ShedLock not lock when Sleuth is present

Tags: scheduled-tasks, spring-cloud-sleuth, shedlock

There is an application that run some process by scheduler, like we have multiple instances we choose **shedlock** to block other run the same process. However, is not working since **sleuth** provides an instances of Runnable which is TraceRunnable and the expected is ScheduledMethodRunnable. Any ideas to solve this?

class SpringLockConfigurationExtractor

```
@Override
public Optional<LockConfiguration> getLockConfiguration(Runnable task) {
    if (task instanceof ScheduledMethodRunnable) {
        ScheduledMethodRunnable scheduledMethodRunnable = (ScheduledMethodRunnable) task;
        return getLockConfiguration(scheduledMethodRunnable.getTarget(), scheduledMethodRunnable.getMethod());
    } else {
        logger.debug("Unknown task type " + task);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I talk with developer and follow documentation set the param interceptMode to **PROXY_METHOD** and its working. He mention that this will be the default value in future releases, in favor of avoid issues like this.

@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "PT5M", interceptMode = PROXY_METHOD)

Comment: Works after adding this annotation!

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to provide your own impl of `SchedulerProxyScheduledLockAdvisor` that verifies the task's class whether it's a `TraceRunnable`. You can also disable parts of Sleuth if necessary. You can also ask Shedlock's authors for some hooks to fix this.

Comment: How do you connect SchedulerProxyScheduledLockAdvisor with SpringLockConfigurationExtractor, since the problem comes in SpringLockConfigurationExtractor.getLockConfiguration? with the instanceof

Comment: afair `@Bean SchedulerProxyScheduledLockAdvisor....` is using what you mentioned. So you could create `SchedulerProxyScheduledLockAdvisor` in such a way that it doesn't use the `SpringLockConfigurationExtractor`